# Giving a div a width and a height aligns it left

Tags: html, css

So the main problem is when I have a div that contains a list of images and I want to make it into a slide gallery and give it a width and a height it will always align on the left.

So, this is my .html code:

```css
.touchgallery {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 800px;
  /* default gallery width */
  height: 600px;
  /* default gallery height */
  background: #eee;
}

.touchgallery ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
  /* image transition. Change 100ms to desired transition duration */
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
}

.touchgallery ul li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 800px;
  text-align: center;
}

.touchgallery ul li img {
  /* CSS for images within gallery */
  width: 95%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="swipegallery" class="touchgallery">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If i remove the width and the height parameters from .touchgallery it will align centered (probably because i wrote that the body is always centered). But as soon as i set width and height again to only show only one image at the same time and not all at once, the image will automatically align on the left and there is nothing I can do about it.

So my questions are:

1. How can I center the div?
2. Why does the width and height parameter cause the div to align on the left?

Comment: Have you tried using `margin: auto` to center the div?

Comment: I've closed an unclosed `<div>` and added some images. Try running the snippet I don't think it reproduce what you're descrining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center the div, you need to use

```css
margin: auto;
```

on .touch-gallery.

I'm guessing that the image aligns to the left because in .touch-gallery ul li, you told it to always float to the left.

```css
.touchgallery ul li{
    display: block;
    width: 800px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}
```